# Using width property for table data cells to change the look of table

Tags: html, html-table, width

```
<table id='tab' border='2'>
<tr><td width="33%">col 1,1</td><td width="33%">col 1,2</td><td width="33%">col 1,3</td></tr>
<tr><td width="50%">col 2,1</td><td width="50%">col 2,2</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%">col 3,1</td><td width="33%">col 3,2</td><td width="33%">col 3,3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Hello I am trying to get all columns in a order, so I am varying the widths of different cells to achieve the requirement. Now the problem is, the table is taking 50% as the table cell width directly and everything gets distorted. How do I work with this?

My html code is being stripped off or rendered even if I use the code tags, how do I insert my HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the second row, it should be

```
<table id='tab' border='2'>
<tr><td width="33%">col 1,1</td><td width="33%">col 1,2</td><td width="33%">col 1,3</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%">col 2,1</td><td width="33%">col 2,2</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%">col 3,1</td><td width="33%">col 3,2</td><td width="33%">col 3,3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or

```
<table id='tab' border='2'>
<tr><td width="33%">col 1,1</td><td width="33%">col 1,2</td><td width="33%">col 1,3</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%">col 2,1</td><td width="66%" colspan="2">col 2,2</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%">col 3,1</td><td width="33%">col 3,2</td><td width="33%">col 3,3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great so does that mean the width of first column be always equal in all rows?? or is the sum of width of all rows should be equal for all rows?

Comment: The sum of all columns should be the same (in this case 99%) for all rows.
In the first case, the cell 2,3 is empty, in the second case, the cell 2,2 is merged with the 2,3.
For further information check: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html
Cheers!

Comment: Ok so my question is if I have a table with varying columns then how would I arrange them?? Say I have 3 rows with 3, 2 and 5 columns then how would I work with that??

Comment: To get the width you have to get the maximum number of columns. Let's say the maximum is 5, then: 100 / 5 = 20%. You can also leave the tds without with ands set a with to the table.

Answer (score 0):

because your second row has only 2 columns and the others have 3?

Comment: well that is the reason I mentioned the width to be 50% on both the columns in the second row. While for the other rows I have 33% width. So shouldn't it be ordered?

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting that you want 3 rows, something like this:

```
| 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 |
|  2,1   |   2,2  |
| 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3 |
```

Based on that expectation, the only way I know to do this without a nested table is to pretend that you have 4 columns and add a `colspan=2` argument to cells (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), and (3,2) as in the following:

```
<table id='tab' border='2'>
<tr><td width="33%">col 1,1</td><td colspan=2 width="33%">col 1,2</td><td width="33%">col 1,3</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 width="50%">col 2,1</td><td colspan=2 width="50%">col 2,2</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%">col 3,1</td><td colspan=2 width="33%">col 3,2</td><td width="33%">col 3,3</td></tr>
</table>
```

To help learn about the various effects that different parameter values have, I recommend the w3schools [editable "Try it" pages](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span).